# Undefined Index - Even with Isset If statement

Tags: php, sql, database

Can anyone tell me why I am getting an Undefined Index error on my code here.
I have used this setup using the if(isset) condition in other parts of my project after
researching my original Undefined Index errors and ISSET fixed my problems. But it is not working here for some reason and I cannot see why.

This form is POSTING the input:

```
<form action="addAlbum_Processed.php" method="POST">
<p>Enter artistID of Artist<input type="number" name="artist_id" maxlength="2" size="2"></p>
<p>Enter name of Album to be created<input type="text" name="album_name" size="20"></p>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"></form>
```

and this page is processing the form input and updating the albums table in my database:

```
<?php    

$connection = mysql_connect('localhost','root','')              
or die(mysql_error());
echo "Connected to php Server <br>";   


or die("Could not select assi2 database");
echo "Connected to assi2 database <br>";


if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$album_name = $_POST['album_name'];
$artist_id = $_POST['artist_id'];
}

$album_name = $_POST['album_name'];
$artist_id = $_POST['artist_id'];

$sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM albums WHERE album = '{$album_name}'";

$result = mysql_query($sqlQuery, $connection) or die("Selection Query Failed !!!");

if (mysql_num_rows($result) != 0)        
{
    header ("Location: Album_Exists.html");
}

else
{
    $sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO albums (ArtistID, Album, delete_marker) 
                  VALUES ('{$artist_id}','{$album_name}','delete_marker = 0')";

    $result = mysql_query($sqlInsert, $connection) or die("Selection Query     Failed !!!");

    header ("Location: addAlbum_Processed.php");
}


mysql_close($connection);

?>
```

I cannot see where I am going wrong. Regards, TW

Comment: `mysql_query` is deprecated.  Look into mysqli or PDO.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**pink box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: This `'delete_marker = 0'` doesn't make sense, if anything that should probably read as `VALUES ('{$artist_id}','{$album_name}', 0)` or `VALUES ('{$artist_id}','{$album_name}', '0')` Plus, get rid of your 2nd `$album_name = $_POST['album_name'];
$artist_id = $_POST['artist_id'];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tiny example of your problem:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$album_name = $_POST['album_name'];
$artist_id = $_POST['artist_id'];
}
```

You check whether a `submit` form field was posted before using the other fields.  So far, so good.  (I would check for the fields that were going to be used, but at least you're checking something.)

But then:

```
$album_name = $_POST['album_name'];
$artist_id = $_POST['artist_id'];
```

You use the fields *anyway*.

What's more...you don't keep from trying to insert stuff if a form isn't being posted.  So any time some rogue spider visits your page, you end up with a blank album in your database.

And that's not even mentioning the fact that you're still using `mysql_query`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$album_name = $_POST['album_name'];
$artist_id = $_POST['artist_id'];
}
```

|***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*____**| first

```
$album_name = $_POST['album_name'];
$artist_id = $_POST['artist_id'];
```

|***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*___**| Repeated

you are fetching variables twice.only one that is if condition is enough.Also use isset for both the variables.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
    if isset($_POST['album_name'])
    $album_name = $_POST['album_name'];
    if isset($_POST['artist_id'])
    $artist_id = $_POST['artist_id'];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like in **addalbam_process.php**

```
<?php    

$connection = mysql_connect('localhost','root','')              
or die(mysql_error());
echo "Connected to php Server <br>";   


or die("Could not select assi2 database");
echo "Connected to assi2 database <br>";


if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
        if(isset($_POST['albam_name']){$album_name = $_POST['album_name']};
        if(isset($_POST['artist_id']){$artist_id = $_POST['artist_id']};
}

$sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM albums WHERE album = '{$album_name}'";

$result = mysql_query($sqlQuery, $connection) or die("Selection Query Failed !!!");

if (mysql_num_rows($result) != 0)        
{
    header ("Location: Album_Exists.html");
}

else
{
    $sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO albums (ArtistID, Album, delete_marker) 
                  VALUES ('{$artist_id}','{$album_name}','delete_marker = 0')";

    $result = mysql_query($sqlInsert, $connection) or die("Selection Query     Failed !!!");

    header ("Location: addAlbum_Processed.php");
}


mysql_close($connection);
```

Please, use MYSQLI or PDO to Prevent SQL INJECTION

Answer (score 0):

here `</form>` is missing
and  try something like this

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$album_name = $_POST['album_name'];
$artist_id = $_POST['artist_id'];
}
```

Comment: hi meddy, the </form> is in the original file. i missed it when copying and pasting. apologies and good spot

Answer (score 0):

A few things.

This line `'delete_marker = 0'` should most probably read as

`VALUES ('{$artist_id}','{$album_name}','0')`

or `VALUES ('{$artist_id}','{$album_name}',0)`

As I read it `'delete_marker = 0'` you are attempting to actually write this value inside the `delete_marker` column `(ArtistID, Album, delete_marker)`

**Or,** you're attempting to use a `WHERE delete_marker = 0` clause, which can't be used in an `INSERT INTO`, but an `UPDATE` or `SELECT` rather.

And your `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` conditional statement should be wrapping your entire code, instead of just your 2 form variables, because it's basically saying "Ok, assign these 2 variables, then ignore the rest if it's NOT set."

Plus, you're repeating those 2 input variables.

```
$album_name = $_POST['album_name'];
$artist_id = $_POST['artist_id'];
```

(I wrapped your entire code inside the `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` conditional statement, btw.

Side note: If you're having a DB connection issue, use this instead:

```
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
if (!$connection) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';
```

PHP **Give this a try:**

Sidenote: If this line fails `VALUES ('{$artist_id}','{$album_name}', 0)` put quotes around the `0` as in `'0'`

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost','root','')              
or die(mysql_error());
echo "Connected to php Server <br>";   

or die("Could not select assi2 database");
echo "Connected to assi2 database <br>";

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$album_name = $_POST['album_name'];
$artist_id = $_POST['artist_id'];

$sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM albums WHERE album = '{$album_name}'";
$result = mysql_query($sqlQuery, $connection) or die("Selection Query Failed !!!");

if (mysql_num_rows($result) != 0)        
{
    header ("Location: Album_Exists.html");
}

else
{
$sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO albums (ArtistID, Album, delete_marker) 
VALUES ('{$artist_id}','{$album_name}', 0)"; // or add quotes around the zero

$result = mysql_query($sqlInsert, $connection) or die("Selection Query Failed !!!");

header ("Location: addAlbum_Processed.php");
}

} // closing brace for if(isset($_POST['submit']))

mysql_close($connection);

?>
```